# llenar input text dependiendo de la selección de una tabla PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Buenas. Estoy realizando un formulario de venta, y necesito saber, como agregar los datos de una fila seleccionada.

Tengo un modal que muestra datos de una tabla **cliente** en mi Base de Datos, cada fila posee un botón de agregar. Al presionar el botón agregar quiero que los datos de esa fila llenen los inputs de texto, y que desaparezca la fila, para poder evitar agregarlo nuevamente, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Este es el código que estoy usando en mi archivo **venta_venta.php**:

```
<?php 
require_once('php/conexion.php');


// REALIZA LA CONSUTLA PARA OBTENER LOS DAToS DE LA TABLA CLIENTE ====================
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);



?>
```

Y este es el codigo de mi modal con el que se muestran los datos de mi tabla **cliente**:

```
  <!-- ========================================================================= Modal ==============================================-->
  <!-- MODAL PARA BUSCAR EL CLIENTE CON EL CUAL SE REALIZARA LA VENTA=============================================================== -->

              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Cliente</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- ===================================== Aqui va el contenido del MODAL ========================================================= -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="idusuario">Buscar cliente:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" REQUIRED class="form-control" id="idusuario" placeholder="Ingresar Nombre">
                                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Nombre</th>
                                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                                        <th>DNI</th>
                                        <th>Direccion</th>
                                        <th>Accion</th>

                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                            // output data of each row
                                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["id_cliente"].'</td><td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td><td>'.$row["apellidos"].'</td><td>'.$row["dni"].'</td><td>'.$row["direccion"].'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus" ></i>&nbsp;Agregar</button></td></tr>';

                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo "0 results";
                                        }


                                        $conn->close();

                                    ?>

                                  </tbody>
                                </table>

<!-- ===================================== Final del contenido del MODAL ========================================================= -->     
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col col-xs-3">
                            <ul class="pagination hidden-xs pull-right">
                              <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



<!-- ===================================== Final del MODAL ========================================================= -->
```

Y esta la parte del codigo en donde quiero que se muestre los datos del cliente seleccionado, aunque solo quiero que se muestre su nombre:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="idusuario">Ingresar cliente:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="idusuario" placeholder="Seleccionar cliente">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Buscar</button>
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo? Perdonen las molestias, pero soy nuevo en programación web.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/163455/86511 @gugadev [Misma duda.. por faor ayuda!!!!!!!! ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/163455/86511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiento que tu formulario **tiene la misma cantidad** de `input` que la cantidad de celdas tiene tu tabla:

Asocias cada botón `Agregar` a una función:

```
<button ... onclick="passRowToForm()">Agregar</button>
```

Esta función solo extrae los valores de las celdas de la fila seleccionada y las pasa al formulario.

```
function passRowToForm() {
    // obtiene la fila seleccionada
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    // itera las celdas de la fila menos la que tiene el botón
    $(row).find('td:not-last-of-type').each(function(i) {
        // por medio de eq obtenemos el input por índice
        // y le agregamos el contenido de la celda
        $('#form input').eq(i).val($(this.text());
    });
}
```

Si quieres que solo muestre su nombre:

```
function passRowToForm() {
    // obtiene la fila seleccionada
    var row = $(this).parent().parent();
    // nth-child(2) porque la celda 'Nombre' es la segunda
    var name = $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    $('input#name').val(name);
}
```